# How to attach/mount EBS volume to Linux Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created a spot instance in which it were specifically requested to attach an EBS snapshot. However that snapshot does not show up in the `/dev/disk/by-label` list

```
$ ll /dev/disk/by-label
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 60 Nov 20 23:43 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 80 Nov 20 23:43 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Nov 20 23:44 cloudimg-rootfs -> ../../xvda1
```

The single entry is for the ***boot disk*** - not the EBS drive.  So ..

(a) Where did the snapshot mentioned in the Spot Request run off to?
(b) Given it did not get attached - how can I do the attach *now* after the fact from the linux command line?

**Update** It was requested about how were the EBS snapshot attached.  I can not give screenshot now: but in any case it was attached via the "Storage" screen: the Snapshot was used to add an EBS Volume to the instance creation request.

Comment: *I created a spot instance in which it were specifically requested to attach an EBS snapshot.* How? This may help. Cheers!!

Comment: I think you'll find that the "boot disk" *is* the EBS volume.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  No, the boot disk is from an existing AMI

Comment: @closetnoc  Updated the op.

Comment: Try `lsblk`.  Try inspecting the instance in the ec2 console, checking how many volumes are attached.  Note also the correct terminology: you don't "attach" a snapshot, you attach a *volume*, which is created from the specified snapshot.  Yes, you can do this now, but first you need to figure out whether it's already there.  It should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be attached to the instance by not mounted and accessible by the operating system.

[Here's how to attach the EBS instance to your EC2 instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html). Suggest you use the console, and you've probably done this already.

[Here's how you make the volume available for use.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html) This is likely the step you're missing. Windows is different, I've not tried that, but you appear to be using Unix.

For example

```
sudo mount /dev/xvdf /vol
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792272/attaching-and-mounting-existing-ebs-volume-to-ec2-instance-filesystem-issue).

Comment: The `lsblk` *does* show two disks. I will follow that info.